# How do I implement multiple mobile store APIs in the same Flash/Flex codebase?

Tags: android, ios, flash, apache-flex, mobile

Q/A style since I already know an answer, but I figured other people might be interested as well. Cleaner implementations and suggestions are more than welcome as well, obviously.

Adobe Flex allows easy cross-platform development for mobile applications, but there is always some functionality that differs between platforms that must be accounted for.

Flex manages this via native extensions, but a native extension for, say, iOS will break your program if loaded into an Android application.

In particular, each platform has its own in-app purchase API. How can one cleanly implement multiple store APIs, since this code inclusion decision needs to be made at compile time and not runtime (where something like Parsley or Swiz would be useful)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using conditional compilation to swap out the actual store implementation class being used at compile time. It has to be done at compile time because loading, say, the iOS Storekit or Android store native extensions while running on your desktop or the other kind of phone Won't Work.

I've created a PurchaseService that is more or less a shell, existing only to inherit and thus implement one of the store implementations:

```
CONFIG::AMAZON
{
import com.zo.comm.amazon.PurchaseServiceImpl;
}

CONFIG::DESKTOP
{ // used for testing without having to copy to a device
import com.zo.comm.desktop.PurchaseServiceImpl;
}

CONFIG::GOOGLE
{
import com.zo.comm.google.PurchaseServiceImpl;
}

CONFIG::IOS
{
import com.zo.comm.ios.PurchaseServiceImpl;
}

public class PurchaseService extends PurchaseServiceImpl
{...}
```

Each PurchaseServiceImpl inherits from a shared, generic PurchaseServiceBase that defines the external interface for the PurchaseService class.

In this fashion, the only conditional compilation code is located in the PurchaseService class. Managing the various compilation flags is a little bit of a chore in Flash Builder, but in an Ant script they are easily passed along to mxmlc:

Flash Builder:

```
-define=CONFIG::DESKTOP,false
-define=CONFIG::IOS,false
-define=CONFIG::ANDROID,true
-define=CONFIG::AMAZON,CONFIG::ANDROID&&false
-define=CONFIG::GOOGLE,CONFIG::ANDROID&&!CONFIG::AMAZON
-define=CONFIG::SANDBOX,false
-define=CONFIG::PRODUCTION,false
-define=CONFIG::STAGING,false
-define=CONFIG::LOCAL,true
```

Note I have a few other things I've left in there just so you can see what other things you might use conditional compilation for. Since most of my config flags are groups of three I just spell them out. If it were a simple "it's IOS if it's not ANDROID" the I would just set IOS to true or false and ANDROID to !CONFIG::IOS, as can be seen in the AMAZON vs. GOOGLE (although I'll have to change that when I add Nook support... :-).

In Ant:

```
  <define name="CONFIG::DESKTOP" value="${output.config.environment.desktop}"/>
  <define name="CONFIG::IOS" value="${output.config.environment.ios}"/>
  <define name="CONFIG::ANDROID" value="${output.config.environment.ios}"/>
  <define name="CONFIG::AMAZON" value="${output.config.environment.amazon}"/>
  <define name="CONFIG::GOOGLE" value="${output.config.environment.google}"/>
  <define name="CONFIG::PRODUCTION" value="${output.config.environment.production}"/>
  <define name="CONFIG::STAGING" value="${output.config.environment.staging}"/>
  <define name="CONFIG::LOCAL" value="${output.config.environment.local}"/>
  <define name="CONFIG::SANDBOX" value="${output.config.environment.sandbox}"/>
```

Note on using conditional compilation for imports: you must use the braces as shown above. The following **will not work**, and the last import will always win:

```
CONFIG::AMAZON
import com.zo.comm.amazon.PurchaseServiceImpl;

CONFIG::DESKTOP
import com.zo.comm.desktop.PurchaseServiceImpl;

CONFIG::GOOGLE
import com.zo.comm.google.PurchaseServiceImpl;

CONFIG::IOS
import com.zo.comm.ios.PurchaseServiceImpl;
```

In Flash Builder you will also need to manage which extensions are included under which platform's builds.